# Ways to configure remote in git

Tags: git

After reading [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_remotes_a_id_remotes_a) , I understood that there are 3 ways to mention url of a remote along with push and pull ref spec in case they are skipped for git push/pull.

> a remote in the Git configuration file: $GIT_DIR/config,
>
> a file in the $GIT_DIR/remotes directory, or
>
> a file in the $GIT_DIR/branches directory.

What is the priority order among them in case conflicting values occur ?

Comment: Please only [ask a single question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/248627). For (a), why not try it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If you consider [`t/t5505-remote.sh#migrate a remote from named file in $GIT_DIR/branches (2)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e8bfb0412581daf8f3c89909f1d37844e8610dd/t/t5505-remote.sh#L836-L847), you will see that a file in `.git/branches/` is actually transformed into a `.gitconfig` remote refspec.

See [`git remote rename`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emrenameem):

> rename the remote named `<old>` to `<new>`.
>   All remote-tracking branches and configuration settings for the remote are updated.
>
> In case `<old>` and `<new>` are the same, and `<old>` is a file under `$GIT_DIR/remotes` or `$GIT_DIR/branches`, the remote is converted to the configuration file format.

So `.gitconfig` is clearly first.
From the tests, `$GIT_DIR/remotes` is second, `$GIT_DIR/branches` is third.