# How to define a remote in git by naming a file in $GIT_DIR/branches

Tags: git

From [git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_named_remote_in_configuration_file) , among 3 ways to define a remote , third one is a [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_named_file_in_code_git_dir_branches_code) . I am not able to understand how should I create this file.

So let us say my remote name be `stash`.
My fetch and push url be `http://someurl`.

Now how should I define the remote using this method ?
Can some one post the file and its contents ? Please take some refspec too in it to make it clearer.

Linked : [Ways to configure remote in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374113/ways-to-configure-remote-in-git/52376514#52376514)

Comment: What's wrong with `git remote add`? ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emaddem)) I mean, is there a specific reason for which you ruled the "typical" way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you reference is for a different use case.  It does *not* define a named remote in the same way that

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

does.  Rather, it maps a particular local branch to a particular branch of a remote (that generally does not have to be mapped as a named remote).

So when you say your remote name is `stash`... that's not exactly applicable.  Remote access defined this way only kinda-sorta has a "remote name".  It has a URL, and maybe a remote branch name, and a local branch name; and when fetching you can use the local branch name *like* a remote name to fetch the remote branch to the local branch.

(By the way, `stash` is not a good name to use for a remote anyway; a `stash` is a specific local data structure in git.)

So when you define access this way, the local branch name is used as the filename, and the file contains the URL (and the remote branch name, if it isn't just the default of `master`).

So for example, suppose you've forked a repo, but you want to periodically pull in updates from a `pub` branch of the original repo (because they use some odd convention where that's the thing you'd want).  You don't care about its other branches (at least most of the time) and don't want to map it as a remote for general use, but you want a shorthand for fetching that one branch's changes into one local branch where you stage integrations.

You could create a file

```
.git/branches/upstream
```

containing the text

```
http://url.of.original/repo#pub
```

Now, you can use `upstream` like a remote name;

```
git fetch upstream
```

would get the changes from the `pub` branch at that URL and update the `upstream` branch accordingly.

Note that unlike a normal remote definition, this does *not* fetch changes to a remote tracking ref from which you can choose to update the local branch.  The fetch directly targets the local branch, and if you locally move the local branch you set yourself up for all kinds of headache.

Circling back around, if you want the remote to be accessed using the name `stash` (which I noted is a bad idea) you would have to therefore name the local branch `stash` as well - and that is even worse, because the `stash` data structure involves a ref called `stash` and the potential for conflict and confusion is very high.

In every case I can think of, it makes more sense to configure the remote using `git config` and then configure custom ref specs for any "special" branch mapping rules.  I'm not sure the history of this alternative method for defining remote access - maybe it's old and used to be seen as useful, or maybe it's new and an explanation of why it was added is out there somewhere I haven't seen.  But either way, just because you can doesn't necessarily mean you should.  The typical method of configuring a remote can accommodate most of not all scenarios, and then anyone looking at it can understand how it's working and why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this method is one of the abandoned experiments that were being done before the concept of a *remote* was invented. Git still supports them, but no one should ever use them for anything today.

Answer (score 0):

I owuld avoid the `.git/branches` folder for... anything.

As illustrated with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), tests are now set so that they still work when the "[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d3874d537af1149c85b73d7c4317ed1b0d0b419/Documentation/git-init.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> template did not create `.git/branches` directory.

See [commit ead7460](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ead74601c6ed7171e9e736e329b45c12d90153e4), [commit 1d75872](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d758728fb26f574169b7f0b420e59af1d0c3c84), [commit ce5369e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce5369e3ef0078458a0608be9ddeb2b276e61b62), [commit 8da0b02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8da0b02d9911d483d34ad8994c879953eebd345c), [commit 93e02b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93e02b6e1e845f5178017c0bac4f18077b331499), [commit e942292](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e942292a3e099f03ae23efd3fd9f09f8b512cadf), [commit dbbb8c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbbb8c50f59005c0c1f2fadbf3972ce89e3f9e72) (03 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d3874d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d3874d537af1149c85b73d7c4317ed1b0d0b419), 18 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`tests`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e942292a3e099f03ae23efd3fd9f09f8b512cadf): don't depend on template-created `.git/branches`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> As noted in [c8a58ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8a58ac5a52b0850fbca87898d1c6aa44cf5626f) (Revert "Don't create the `$GIT_DIR/branches` directory on init", 2009-10-31, Git v1.6.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8a58ac5a52b0850fbca87898d1c6aa44cf5626f)) there was an attempt long ago in [0cc5691](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc5691a8b05a7eabdeef520c94b1bb3bcac7874) ("Don't create the `$GIT_DIR/branches` directory on init", 2009-10-30, Git v1.6.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc5691a8b05a7eabdeef520c94b1bb3bcac7874)) to get rid of the legacy "`branches`" directory.
>
> We should probably get rid of its creation by removing the "`templates/branches--`" file.
> But whatever our default behavior, our tests should be tightened up to explicitly create the `.git/branches` directory if they rely on our default templates, to make the dependency on those templates clear.
>
> So let's amend the two tests that would fail if `.git/branches` wasn't created.
> To do this introduce a new `"TEST_CREATE_REPO_NO_TEMPLATE"` variable, which we'll set before sourcing test-lib.sh, and change the "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e942292a3e099f03ae23efd3fd9f09f8b512cadf/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> and [`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e942292a3e099f03ae23efd3fd9f09f8b512cadf/Documentation/git-init.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> commands in the tests themselves to explicitly pass --template=".
>
> This way they won't get a `.git/branches` in either their top-level `.git`, or in the ones they create.
> We can then amend the tests that rely on the "`.git/branches`" directory existing to create it explicitly, and to remove it after its creation.

As noted by torek, a `git remote add upstream` is safer.